# CS0116 A namespace cannot directly contain members such as field or methods C# Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

Tags: c#, .net, interop, office-interop

Working on [Office Interop Objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interop/how-to-access-office-onterop-objects) using `C#` and I am facing an error, here is the main part where there is the error:

```cs
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
```

...

```cs
static void DisplayInExcel (IEnumerable<Account> accounts)

{
    var excelApp = new Excel.Application();
    excelApp.Visible = true;
    excelApp.Workbooks.Add();
    Excel._Worksheet workSheet = (Excel.Worksheet).excelApp.ActiveSheet;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the full class? its seems that your method is outside the class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably missed class declaration in your code. Now you have something like this:

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    static void DisplayInExcel (IEnumerable<Account> accounts)
    {
        var excelApp = new Excel.Application();
        excelApp.Visible = true;
        excelApp.Workbooks.Add();
        Excel._Worksheet workSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)excelApp.ActiveSheet;
    }
}
```

And you need to wrap your function with a class

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    public class MyClass
    {
        public static void DisplayInExcel (IEnumerable<Account> accounts)
        {
            var excelApp = new Excel.Application();
            excelApp.Visible = true;
            excelApp.Workbooks.Add();
            Excel._Worksheet workSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)excelApp.ActiveSheet;
        }
    }
}
```

and then access it like this

```
MyClass.DisplayInExcel(accounts)
```